# Locating and returning sub-string up to space in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

So say I have some string

```
'xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx model:MODEL_NAME xxxxx'
```

Is there a way I can search the string for the sub-string `model:` and then return a sub-string that contains everything up to the next space in the string.

So the `MODEL_NAME` will vary in each string but I would like it to return in this example `model:MODEL_NAME` after locating `model:`

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the most eloquent solution however I have found this to work

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(TRIM(example.Trimmed), 1,LOCATE(' ', TRIM(example.Trimmed))-1) Desired

FROM
(SELECT
    SUBSTR('xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx model:MODEL_NAME xxxxx',
    LOCATE('model:','xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx model:MODEL_NAME xxxxx')-1) as Trimmed
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) example;
```

First the sub-query locates the word model and returns everything to the right of it (inclusive) and stores it as a table 'example'.
It then locates the space and returns everything to the left of it as a substring.